# Gradle specify build binaries names from command line

Tags: jar, gradle

I need to specify build binaries names from command line in Gradle.

like:

```
gradle -arg: filename.jar
```

I will use it in

```
jar{
     archiveName = "something.jar"
}
```

and

```
war{
    war.archiveName = "something.war"
}
```

Just how to pass a parameter into build.gradle and use that string from command line argument.

Comment: You should be able to pass the gradle property as `gradle build -PjarName=myJar` and then use it inside your build. Please provide more details if that does not solve your issue.

Comment: this did not do. would be ideal to pass an parameter to the thing and use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In build.gradle:

```
jar {
    archiveName = myName
}
```

In command line:

```
gradle jar -PmyName=customName.jar
```

Comment: jar {archiveName ="$word1"}. gradle build -Pversion=7.77 Also works.